# try to create a foreign key but its showing a error

Tags: sql-server

I was trying to create code as FK in 'school info' table
and its showing me this error

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_school info_school info1'.
>       The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_school info_school info1". The conflict occurred in database "excel database", table "dbo.school info", column 'school_code'.
>
> 'school info' table
>       - Unable to create relationship 'FK_school info_school info1'.
>       The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint "FK_school info_school info1". The conflict occurred in database "excel database", table "dbo.school info", column 'school_code'.

Comment: Hello, Rishab! Welcome to the SO. As to your question, it is a bit unclear what columns are in your table. May you update your answer with structure of tables your are trying to manipulate?

Answer (score 0):

Rishab,

maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962457/alter-table-statement-conflicted-with-the-foreign-key-same-table-constraint) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25868980/foreign-key-same-table-error-but-foreign-key-doesnt-exist) will help.

Please do a bit of research before posting questions, as this is really something with a lot of results when you google for ["The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+ALTER+TABLE+statement+conflicted+with+the+FOREIGN+KEY+SAME+TABLE+constraint%22). Just use the error message, leave out any specific things like database, table or column names and enter the phrase in the search field...